# How to locate relevant tables or columns in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have imported 1000 sample rows from various tables into a SQL Server (let's call it `SQLServer1`).

I have also imported the rows into the second SQL Server (`SQLServer2`).

When I execute the following query on `SQLServer2`, I get no results, however when I execute the same query on `SQLServer1`, I get the expected results.

This is because I haven't imported all the rows from `SQLServer1` to `SQLServer2`.

The problem is that I can't import all the data from `SQLServer1` to `SQLServer2` because some tables contain over 3 million rows.

Therefore, can someone let me know if there is a way to find out exactly data is required from the tables in `SQLServer1` to get a result from `SQLServer2`?

Basically, I need to import only those rows into `SQLServer2`, that will produce the same result in `SQLServer1`.

I believe I would need to do apply some kind of `DISTINCT` clause or a `LEFT / RIGHT JOIN` to determine the rows/columns/data that is present in `SQLServer1` that is not present in `SQLServer2`, but I'm not sure.

The tables look like the following:

[image]

Sample code is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable 
(
    MakeName nvarchar(100),
    ModelName nvarchar(150),
    Cost money
)

INSERT #tmpTable 
VALUES (N'Ferrari', N'Testarossa', 52000.00),
       (N'Ferrari', N'355', 176000.00),
       (N'Porsche', N'911', 15600.00),
       (N'Porsche', N'924', 9200.00),
       (N'Porsche', N'944', 15960.00),
       (N'Ferrari', N'Testarossa', 176000.00),
       (N'Aston Martin', N'DB4', 23600.00),
       (N'Aston Martin', N'DB5', 39600.00)
```

Any thoughts?

The code is as follows:

```
SELECT Make.MakeName, Model.ModelName, Stock.Cost 
FROM Data.Stock
INNER JOIN Data.Model ON Model.ModelID = Stock.ModelID
INNER JOIN Data.Make ON Make.MakeID = Model.MakeID
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to connect this servers together and the run merge command, take a read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the permissions to connect to the server in the way you described

Comment: Hi - in your question you state “ When I execute the following query…” but then you don’t seem to give a query. It’s very unclear, to me, what you are trying to do.  Can you update your question to provide further explanation, please?

Comment: Hi @NickW, thanks for getting in touch, I have included the code

Comment: I think the resolution is to do somekind of left join to identify data that is missing.

Comment: What is your ***real*** goal here. Are you setting up a smaller database for development and testing? Are you populating a database with just the "recent" active data for reporting purposes? Are you filtering the data to create a subset by some criteria like dealership? One approach would be to: (1) Pick an initial condition on one table. (2) Load all selected PK values from that table into a temp table like #Selected(TableName, PKValue). (3) Follow all FK relationships to select keys from related tables. (4) Use those results to select the rows for the final transfer.

Comment: Basically, the whole idea is just to identify what rows are needed to get results from the query

Comment: @TN, yes, I'm setting up a smaller database for development and testing? But I would like to use the data used from the production database. As I mentioned, if I were to execute the code on the production database I **would** get a result, but because I'm running the query on my database with a subset of the data from the production the query is missing the data needed ... does that make sense?

Comment: With no `WHERE` condition on your query, what makes you think that you don't need all rows from all three tables? I expect you *will definitely* need all rows from the `Stock` table. While there might be some unreferenced rows in `Model` and `Make` table, I suspect those tables contain relatively few rows compared to `Stock`, so there is little saved by pulling a subset.

Comment: @Patterson Is there any personally identifiable information (PII) in the database? If so, it might be safer to look into test data generators.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I never thought of that. There is PII data, so I think it wise to generate to dummy data.

Comment: I just thought there might be a quick way to find data from the sql server that I would need to genrate the same results from my dummy data